# JQTransform Reset Form?

Tags: jquery, jqtransform

I'm trying to do a reset on a form styled with JQTransform, in particular selects, which are replaced by lists.  There is a function jqTransformReset(); but I cant get it working for some reason.

Has anyone had any success with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass jqTransformReset() the form element as a parameter.

There is some additional information regarding jqTransform and <select> elements over here:

http://www.code-pal.com/the-select-problem-after-using-jqtransform-and-its-solution/

Answer (score 1):

Your code keeps the value because when i "submit" the form, the old value is sent.
This worked fine to me.

```
$("div.jqTransformSelectWrapper").each(function() {
         $(this).show();
         $("ul li:first a", this).click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To reset the select drop downs in jqTransform you can use this code in `jqTransformReset()` in `jquery.jqtransform.js`

```
$("div.jqTransformSelectWrapper").each(function() {
        $("div span", this).text($("ul li:first", this).text());
        $("ul li a.selected", this).removeClass("selected");
        $("ul li:first a", this).addClass("selected");
    });
```